# Does assignment to a property cause a retain?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, properties

A very basic question, when I have something like:

```
 TTStyledText * text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:message.message lineBreaks:YES URLs:NO];
 text.width = self.frame.size.width - 60;
 text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:17.0];
 _main_title.text = text;
```

When I assign `text` to `_main_title.text`, does it mean that `_main_title.text` retains `text`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it means that **you shouldn't care if `_main_title.text` retains `text` or not**.

That would be entirely an implementation detail of the setter method.  It might copy the text. It might do something whacky internally.  *You shouldn't need to know.*

You should only need to worry about the memory management in your code and, in that code, your memory management is correct.

Finally, if you want `text` to survive beyond the end of that particular scope, then *you should retain it* (and release it later).

Comment: And, to emphasize, “you should retain it” does not mean “you should hope `_main_title` retains it”. Let `_main_title` retain it or not as it sees fit; if *you* care about whether the object lives or dies, retain it yourself (or assign it to a retaining property of your own) and release it (or assign `nil` to the same property) when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If `text` is a `retain` property of whatever class `_main_title` belongs to, or `_main_title`'s class implements a `setText:` method that retains its argument, then yes.

Comment: you mean if I defined @property (nonatomic, retain) TTStyledTextLabel * main_title; then text is retained?